# Android thread queue

Tags: android, multithreading

I'd like to have a queue of work/tasks to be done on a separate thread, but can only process one work at a time. So not simultaneously.

Is there something built-in android for this?

Thanks,

EDIT: 
The work = get information from Database. Once done, update the UI with the fetched information.

Comment: Typically, reading DB is done on the 'separate thread', but updating the UI must be done in the main thread.  So these tasks would not be done sequentially on the same thread.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you checked out java.util.concurrent.Executors ? You could do something like this:

```
final static ExecutorService tpe = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
...
tpe.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // your work
    }
}):
```

It's not android specific, it is part of the jdk5.

From the doc:

> Creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread operating off an
>   unbounded queue. (Note however that if this single thread terminates
>   due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will
>   take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.) Tasks are
>   guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be
>   active at any given time. Unlike the otherwise equivalent
>   newFixedThreadPool(1) the returned executor is guaranteed not to be
>   reconfigurable to use additional threads.

Comment: I believe that I could update the UI thread when work is completed ?

Comment: Usual thing, when the work is done you can change your UI either executing on ui thread or posting a msg using an handler

Comment: Awesome, saved me hours.

Answer (score 3):

If you want something can do work independently from the activity lifecycle that can do queued work, you should take a look at [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). It can spin up, do discrete blocks of work asynchronously then finish itself when all its tasks are completed.

If you don't need anything that can live without any activities, Java has [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) along with several different implementations.

Answer (score 0):

In Android You can also consider about Loader framework.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Comment: Loaders are deprecated.